# Phaser : how to catch the game.scale.refresh end event

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am actualy developing my first game using [phaser](http://phaser.io) and I did a function resize to resize the game follow the size of the screen and at the end of this function I do :

```
game.scale.refresh();
```

But I would like to catch the event of this function like this :

```
var scaleRefresh = game.scale.refresh();
scaleRefresh.onComplete.add(function(){
    //DO stuff
});
```

But it's not work how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need a resize function? I didn't implement it, and my game already does something similar when your desired behavior.

Which SCALE_MODE are you using? try to use 'USER_SCALE'.
Also, the documentation about Refresh doesn't say something about an onComplete event. but:

"The queued layout refresh is not immediate but will run promptly in an upcoming preRender."

https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#refresh

Seems that you could do your "onComplete" logic at "preRender" on your state.